# Formatting JSON in an AJAX call

Tags: jquery, json

So I have an MVC action with the header:

```
public PartialViewResult PersistPlaceholderItems(ModelObject model, int start, int count)
```

So it's expecting three things. First thing is an object, the other two are just simple ints.

This is what I have so far for my AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(model),
            success: function (result) {
                $("#panel").html(result);
            },
            error: function (event) {
                alert("Error!");
            }
        });
```

Stringifying model just gives me the first thing I need in PersistPlaceholderItems. I need start and count as well. I just don't know how to format the JSON string to include them along with the model object.

I tried:

```
data: [{model: JSON.stringify(model)}, {start:start}, {count:count}]
```

But it gave me an error. How do I format it so I can send all three items to the server?

Edit: Ideally, I would like to just send three things instead of having to wrap it into another viewmodel. I don't want a viewmodel inside of a viewmodel just so I can send two additional ints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need:

```
data: {model: model, start:start, count:count}
```

Comment: This put me on the right track. What I had to do was this: data: JSON.stringify({model:model, start:start, count:count})